# How to store the address of the previous function caller?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, nft

```
function AuctionNft(string memory _name) public payable {
    MyNft storage nft = fetchNft[_name];
    // bidders storage _bidders = bidderslist[msg.sender]
    require(nft.isAuctionable, "This nft is not listed for auction yet");
    require(block.timestamp <= timer,"Auction for this NFt has been ended");
    require(msg.value >= minBid, "Minimum Bid is not met");
    
    address currentBidder = msg.sender;
    bidders storage prevbidder = previousBidder[currentBidder];
    prevbidder.Address = msg.sender;
    prevbidder.bidAmount = 0;
    
    address payable recipient = payable(nft.owner);
    require(msg.value > currentBid, "Bid is lower than the previous bid");
    currentBid = msg.value * 1 ether;
    if (block.timestamp > timer) {
        recipient.transfer(currentBid);
        nft.owner = currentBidder;
        nft.isOnSale = false;
        nft.isAuctionable = false;
    }
}
```

In the above code I'm trying to create a function to Auction the Nft, however, when placing the bids if the current bid is higher than the previous bid what I want is to transfer the bid placed by the previous bidder back to its account.

For that reason, I want to store the address and msg. value of the previous bidder, however, I'm unable to think of any proper logic on how should I do it!!!.

I've created a struct object prevbidder having variable address and amount where I wanna save previous bidder's address and msg.value.

Please help me in understanding how can I store the address and msg.value of the previous bidder.

Answer (score 0):

There are some logic errors in your code.

1. `currentBid = msg.value * 1 ether` - Is there any reason to mutiply 1 ether on msg.value ?
2. `if (block.timestamp > timer)` - you already have `require(block.timestamp <= timer,"Auction for this NFt has been ended")` above, another timer check here doesn't make any sense.
3. not sure if your MyNft is ERC721 standard or not, the standard way to transfer ownership is via `transferFrom` or `safeTransferFrom`

I revise your code a little bit , you can check if this is what you want.

```
contract Auction {

    struct Bidder {
        address addr;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    uint256 puiblic currentBid;

    mapping(string => Bidder) public nftHighestBidders;

    uint256 private constant minBid = 0.1 ether;
    
    uint256 private constant timer = block.timestamp + 5 days;


    function AuctionNft(string memory _name) public payable {
        MyNft storage nft = fetchNft[_name];

        require(nft.isAuctionable, "This nft is not listed for auction yet");
        require(block.timestamp <= timer,"Auction for this NFt has been ended");
        require(msg.value >= minBid, "Minimum Bid is not met");
        require(msg.value > currentBid, "Bid is lower than the previous bid");

        address currentBidder = msg.sender;
        Bidder storage highestBidder = nftHighestBidders[_name];
        
        address payable recipient = payable(nft.owner);

        recipient.transfer(msg.value);
        nft.owner = currentBidder;

        currentBid = msg.value;

        highestBidder.addr = msg.sender;
        highestBidder.amount = msg.value;
    }
}
```